# Very bad results for tracking a marker with SURF and FLANN

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

What I want to do is to track a marker (rather small peace of paper with drawings on it). I just want to know if it is there or not. I've been looking at many different algorithms like finding contours in case I make the marker a simple geometrical shape (a star cut out from paper) and of course the more serious stuff like SIFT and SURF.

Right now I'm trying out SURF with FLANN and the code I use is this one (with nearly no modifications):
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

The problem is the results are really not good:
[My results http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8729/xpu5.jpg](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/8729/xpu5.jpg)

It's like I get matches with everything else besides my marker... even the few lucky matches I get with the marker are not the same between the 2 images. This is a big problem since my "real world" application of this will be in a very "noisy" environment with lots of objects and not on white uniform background with camera shaking a bit so maybe also blurry. Also at first I wanted to use a marker a lot smaller then this one (current_size/4).

So my question is, how can I improve accuracy ? Should a make a more complicated marker with more texture and so on (since I read that SURF/SIFT is bad at detecting objects with low texture) ? would another matcher make much of a difference or should I use SIFT maybe ?
Alternatively, would another approach/algorithm be better for markers ? Knowing that it wouldn't be a problem if the marker was detected only if it is completely visible and not just part of it (it would actually be more convenient for me this way). I've used some marker based AR so I know those libraries are good at it but I have no idea what kind of algorithms they use.
In any case, sample code, links or just an advice would be greatly appreciated.

Some additional useful info: I'm running this on a raspberry Pi (C++ OpenCV, Linux Debian), with it's integrated camera board so the resolution isn't the best and it's slow (1-2min for the code to run) but it's not a problem, I'm not really aiming for real-time (would be nice though).
For this test I used huge images (2592x1944) because I wanted the results to be as good as possible. Should I change the resolution to 800x600 ? will that increase accuracy for some weird reason ?

EDIT: as requested, my original images:
http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/2329/5a93.jpg
http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/847/cwg8.jpg

EDIT2: I just run the Brute Force Matcher and got the EXACT same results and when I say exact I really mean exact. Posting a screen shot would be copying my previous screen shot. Now I'm beginning to think it's my images that are just bad. Would it be wise to take a photo of the reference image with a better camera and use it to match images taken by the other one (the one I use now on my Pi) ? I know camera parameters could play some role, hence my question.

Comment: please upload your original images

Comment: Sure, here you go (see edit). :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Take a look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZNYoL8rzPY

it shows much better results on a similar application. Perhaps you should use their code (there's a link for downloading it in the "about" section of the video).

Comment: Hmmm brief looks interesting. I think I'll try it out. Thanks ! But non the less, I would really like to know why my marker detection failed earlier and if other methods are preferable to SIFT/SURF.

Comment: @GilLevi Well the problem is that I don't find any appropriate matches with the method I just tried. Weird thing is that I have used SIFT with VLFeat in matlab and the results where really good at that time (other images where used with more texture, real objects and so on). Right now I want to use OpenCV and C++ and the results I get are just disappointing...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not sure why that fails, especially if your'e saying it worked with Matlab. Maybe the marker lacks texture. Perhaps you should also ask in the OpenCV Q&A forum. For general knowledge, BRIEF is less accurate then SIFT.

Comment: Isn't your marker image of very low resolution?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK That's the best I could do with: https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi-camera-board
Maybe I should try making a proper marker and printing it out. :/

Comment: @GilLevi Well I'm saying I played around with the matlab version of SIFT/SURF on other images and had better results (like 6 monts ago). So results like these kind of worry me.

Comment: It seems to me that the difference between the Matlab algorithm and this algorithm is FLANN. vl_feat uses a different matching, right? 

If running times are not of the essence, why should you use FLANN instead of a better method for matching?

Comment: Also, are there any other differences between the Matlab algorithm and the C++ algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem might be with the pattern and its lack of distinguishing characteristics. Have you thought about changing the pattern? Try something like a checkerboard that people use for calibration. Perhaps, that will give you more matches.

You should also investigate RANSAC to determine which of all matches given by the program is correct the matches. RANSAC can work in quite noisy conditions.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while since I've made this post but for the sake of completeness, I want to say that using other images gave me pretty much the same results. This time I took very distinguishable images of a badge. In the end I had to go with the Generalised Hough Transform for my project instead. I'm still curiouser as to why it didn't work properly for me.

Comment: I know that SURF and SIFT can be memory greedy, so running them on a Raspberry Pi might have had something to do with that (it was an embedded systems project with a Pi and its camera board). But when I checked RAM and CPU consumption, I didn't really see any memory problems. Weird.